# Why does benchmarking with wrk give weird results when working with Go and MySQL?

Tags: go

It started out with me trying to see how much of a difference there was between prepared statements and non prepared statements. I ended up sitting for 5 hours trying to figure out what was going on. And what I found out makes no sense.

I am using CentOS 7 with supervisord to run Go 1.4.2 in the background as a deamon. I am using MariaDB as the sql database.

The program I am benchmarking is really simple.

I tried to do this in 3 different ways.

1 (the most uncorrect way which for some reason works best):

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

type User struct {
    Id       int64
    Email    string
    Username string
}

var DB *sql.DB

func getUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    query := `SELECT id, email, username FROM user WHERE id=3 LIMIT 1;`

    rows, _ := DB.Query(query)

    var users []*User
    for rows.Next() {
        u := new(User)
        rows.Scan(&u.Id, &u.Email, &u.Username)
        users = append(users, u)
    }

    fmt.Fprint(w, users[0])
}

func main() {
    // runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)

    var err error
    DB, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:pass@unix(/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock)/dbname?charset=utf8")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err = DB.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/api/user", getUser)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", router))
}
```

I did not check for any errors here. I did not close any rows and so on.

This method gives great results with wrk:

```
Running 5s test @ http://127.0.0.1:80/api/user
  1 threads and 1000 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    18.85ms   17.73ms 238.81ms   91.57%
    Req/Sec     7.19k     1.58k    8.45k    96.00%
  35776 requests in 5.04s, 5.02MB read
Requests/sec:   7096.50
Transfer/sec:      0.99MB
```

I seem to get a r/s over 7000 consistently. Great result when I am getting stuff from the MySQL database.

In the second method I'll just replace the content inside the getUser function like this:

```
func getUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    query := `SELECT id, email, username FROM user WHERE id=3 LIMIT 1;`

    rows, err := DB.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var users []*User
    for rows.Next() {
        u := new(User)
        err := rows.Scan(&u.Id, &u.Email, &u.Username)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        users = append(users, u)
    }

    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Fprint(w, users[0])
}
```

This is the recommended way of doing a query as I understood:
http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html

This gives really weird and awful results consistently!

```
Running 5s test @ http://127.0.0.1:80/api/user
  1 threads and 1000 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    11.80ms    3.68ms  14.40ms  100.00%
    Req/Sec     0.00      0.00     0.00    100.00%
  2 requests in 5.01s, 294.00B read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 1490, write 159932, timeout 0
Requests/sec:      0.40
Transfer/sec:      58.64B
```

And only when I decrease the connections amount do I seem to get better results, but not consistently, the results sometimes go all the way down to around 1500 r/s, it makes no sense to me.

The third way I tried is this: (Just doing a simple 1 row query)

```
func getUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    query := `SELECT id, email, username FROM user WHERE id=3 LIMIT 1;`

    user := new(User)
    err := DB.QueryRow(query).Scan(&user.Id, &user.Email, &user.Username)

    if err != nil {
        if err != sql.ErrNoRows {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusNotFound), http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }

    fmt.Fprint(w, user)
}
```

Here I get the same awful results, less than 1 request per second.

What is going on? This has been bugging me for hours now. Hope someone has an explanation and a fix to this..

EDIT:

Now I removed all the lines with `log.Fatal(err)` and replaced them with `log.Println(err)`

And set

```
runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)
```

And the single query one gives me results like these consistently:

```
[root@centos7 main]# wrk -t1 -c1000 -d5s http://127.0.0.1:80/api/user
Running 5s test @ http://127.0.0.1:80/api/user
  1 threads and 1000 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    22.24ms   12.11ms 176.58ms   79.83%
    Req/Sec    38.01k     4.62k   48.75k    66.67%
  188080 requests in 5.04s, 24.09MB read
  Non-2xx or 3xx responses: 183505
Requests/sec:  37350.28
Transfer/sec:      4.78MB
```

But is this not too good? Must be something wrong here?

Another thing, are you not supposed to be using `log.Fatal(err)` in a production server but only when developing? Since all the examples on how to use the MySQL driver shows examples with `log.Fatal(err)` after each err when getting results.

Comment: Just a note on the benchmark: this won't test the database at all as it's written now. It will just get values from the cache since the whole query is constant.

Comment: Thanks I did not know that. How can I test the database then?

Comment: You will have to run random IDs into a database with lots of users, and even then you're testing only that table (which might fit into memory). But it will give more realistic values than always getting the same value.

Comment: Ok Thanks man! Do you know if it is a bad idea to use log.Fatal(err) on a production server when checking for errors after queries? Does it not shut down the server since it is always running and blocking?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not knowledgeable about Go so can't help with the actual issue.

Comment: So in what example do you use prepared statements? The beginning of the question addresses it, then nothing like that in the code.

Comment: There are no prepared statements because I run into a bigger issue as explained in the post.

Comment: You appear to be starving your machine of sockets: evidenced by the `Socket errors: connect 0, read 1490, write 159932, timeout 0` from your wrk results. Both your Go application, wrk and MySQL are competing for TCP sockets on your machine. Without any tuning, it's easy to 'run out'.

Comment: Thanks Elithrar. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: When I do $ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max , I get "383893" as output. When I do $ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr, I get "1088    0       383893" as output